# JAVA - not able to update data in file that is "resources" folder

Tags: java

I am a little perplexed by the behavior I see in my proof-of-concept test program.

My Java application uses a file that is placed in "resource" folder in the Java project.  The application will occasionally read numeric data from it, use it, increment the number and write it back to the same file for the next cycle.

The following test application mimics the above (wanted) behavior:

```
public class ReadWriteFile {
    private static final String TEMP_EMAIL_ID_DATAFILE_PATH = "main/resources/TempEmailId.dat";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        try {
            int id = readTempId();
            System.out.println("Current value = " + id);
            writeTempId(id+5);
            System.out.println("Updated value = " + readTempId());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int readTempId() throws IOException {

         InputStream is = ReadWriteFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(TEMP_EMAIL_ID_DATAFILE_PATH);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        int currentValue = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            currentValue = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        br.close();

        return currentValue;
    }

    public static void writeTempId(int currentId) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src" + File.separator + TEMP_EMAIL_ID_DATAFILE_PATH));

        bw.write(Integer.toString(Math.abs(currentId)));

        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

        return;
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the following is seen:

```
Current value = 100000054
Updated value = 100000054
```

My gut feeling is that the use of

```
ReadWriteFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(TEMP_EMAIL_ID_DATAFILE_PATH);
```

is causing the issue.  I am using this to access the file within the JAVA project.

Can it be true?

Also, note that for creating the BufferedWriter object, I have to pre-pend the Java constant with "src/" - else the file could not be found :(

Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you cant as the resources are compiled with the jar, I believe when you run it again or compile again the data should be updated. I may be wrong though.

Comment: That makes sense.  I will move the dynamic file out of the compiled JAR file.  MANY THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class ReadWriteFile {
    private static final String TEMP_EMAIL_ID_DATAFILE_PATH = "TempEmailId.dat";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, URISyntaxException {
        try {
            int id = readTempId();
            System.out.println("Current value = " + id);
            writeTempId(id+5);
            System.out.println("Updated value = " + readTempId());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int readTempId() throws IOException {

        InputStream is = ReadWriteFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(TEMP_EMAIL_ID_DATAFILE_PATH);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        int currentValue = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            currentValue = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        br.close();

        return currentValue;
    }

    public static void writeTempId(int currentId) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        URL resource = ReadWriteFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource(TEMP_EMAIL_ID_DATAFILE_PATH);
        File file = new File(resource.toURI());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        bw.write(Integer.toString(Math.abs(currentId)));

        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

        return;
    }
}
```

The 2 key lines for writing to file was doing it as such:

```java
        URL resource = ReadWriteFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource(TEMP_EMAIL_ID_DATAFILE_PATH);
        File file = new File(resource.toURI());
```

Comment: I will move the file out of the executable JAR - but will use your solution also.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Resources are intended to be read-only. The only way they could become writable is if they were extracted into the file system, but that's not how they are intended to be used and is not portable as resources are normally in a jar. Write to a *file* instead